# Having problems forming a linq subquery in my Application Context

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Here is an example of the SQL I am trying to convert to Linq

```
SELECT 
*  FROM assetassignment 
              WHERE asgn_type = 'trc' AND asgn_id = '54490' AND lgh_number <> 3015097 AND mov_number <>2030782
                     and asgn_enddate in (select max(asgn_enddate) FROM assetassignment 
                        WHERE asgn_type = 'trc' AND asgn_id = '54490' AND lgh_number <> 3015097 AND mov_number <> 2030782 and asgn_enddate <= '03/19/2017')
```

I need to convert this to Linq.  I am using a repository as follows:

```
public async task<AssetAssignment> FindPreviousTrip(string tractorNumber, DateTime endDate, int legNumber,string moveNumber)
    {
        using (var ctx = new AssetAssignmentContext(_nameOrConnectionString))
        {
            var previousTrip = from a in ctx.Set<AssetAssignment>()
                                    where a.AssignmentType == "TRC" &&
                                    a.AssignmentId == tractorNumber &&
                                    a.LegId == legNumber &&
                                    a.MoveNumber == moveNumber &&
                                    a.EndDate).in()



        }
    }
```

As you can see I am making a stab at it, but keep failing on the subquery for the EndDate in statement.

I'll keep plugging at it, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider using `Contains`. Your SQL confused me - it has `<>` instead of `=` for `lgh_number` (is that the same as `LegId` ?) and it has no group for the `SELECT MAX()` so that would return one value and you don't need `IN` for one value, just `=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var previousTrip = from a in ctx.Set<AssetAssignment>()
      where a.AssignmentType == "TRC" &&
            a.AssignmentId == tractorNumber &&
            a.LegId != legNumber &&
            a.MoveNumber != moveNumber &&
            a.EndDate == (from b in ctx.Set<AssetAssignment>()
                          where b.AssignmentType == "TRC" && b.AssignmentId == tractorNumber && b.LegId != legNumber && b.MoveNumber != moveNumber && b.EndDate <= new DateTime(2017, 19, 3)
                          select b.EndDate).Max()
        select a;
```

You may want to create a variable for the common query

```
var baseTrip = from a in ctx.Set<AssetAssignment>()
           where a.AssignmentType == "TRC" &&
                 a.AssignmentId == tractorNumber &&
                 a.LegId != legNumber &&
                 a.MoveNumber != moveNumber
           select a;

var previousTrip = from a in baseTrip
               where a.EndDate == (from b in baseTrip where b.EndDate <= new DateTime(2017, 19, 3) select b.EndDate).Max()
               select a;
```

Comment: Great thanks for the suggestion, this work excellent.  I didn't think about the variable for the common query.